# SQL Server nvarchar(max) vs nvarchar(n) affects performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This is SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2.  I have 2 tables.  Both are identical (data and indexing), except the first table has a VALUE column as `nvarchar(max)` and the second has the same column as `nvarchar(800)`.  This column is included in a non-clustered index.  I also created a clustered index on both tables.  I have also rebuilt the indexes.  The max string length in this column is 650.

If I run the same query against both the `nvarchar(800)` table is consistently faster, many times twice as fast.  Sure seems like it is defeating the purpose of "varchar". Table contains 800,000+ rows.  The query should be looking at around 110,000 rows (which is what the plan estimates).

According to the io stats there are no lob reads, so everything appears to be in row.  Execution plans are the same, except there is a slight difference in the cost percentage between the two tables and the estimated row size is bigger with the `nvarchar(max)` (91 bytes vs 63 bytes).  The number of reads are pretty much the same too.

Why the difference?

=====   Schema   ======

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
        [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [ProductID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [ProductSkeletonID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [Value] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
        [IsKeywordSearchable] [bit] NULL,
        [ValueInteger] [bigint] NULL,
        [ValueDecimal] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
        [ValueDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [TypeOfData] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_table1_productskeletonid] ON [dbo].[table1] 
    (
        [ProductSkeletonID] ASC
    )
    INCLUDE ( [ProductID],
    [Value]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table2](
        [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [ProductID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [ProductSkeletonID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [Value] [nvarchar](800) NOT NULL,
        [IsKeywordSearchable] [bit] NULL,
        [ValueInteger] [bigint] NULL,
        [ValueDecimal] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
        [ValueDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [TypeOfData] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_table2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_table2_productskeletonid] ON [dbo].[table2] 
    (
        [ProductSkeletonID] ASC
    )
    INCLUDE ( [ProductID],
    [Value]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_results](
    [SearchID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [RowNbr] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PermissionList] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [SearchWeight] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_table_results] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [SearchID] ASC,
    [RowNbr] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_table_results_SearchID] ON [dbo].[cart_product_searches_results] 
(
    [SearchID] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [ProductID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

===== Table1 query ======

```
    SELECT cppev.ProductSkeletonID, cppev.Value, COUNT(*) AS Value FROM table1 cppev
    JOIN search_results cpsr ON cppev.ProductID = cpsr.ProductID AND cpsr.SearchID = 227568 
    WHERE cppev.ProductSkeletonID in (3191, 3160, 3158, 3201)
    GROUP BY cppev.ProductSkeletonID, cppev.Value

    Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
    Table 'table1'. Scan count 4, logical reads 582, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
    Table 'table_results'. Scan count 1, logical reads 82, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

    SQL Server Execution Times:
       CPU time = 1373 ms,  elapsed time = 1576 ms.

 |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1005]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1008],0)))
       |--Stream Aggregate(GROUP BY:([cppev].[Value], [cppev].[ProductSkeletonID]) DEFINE:([Expr1008]=Count(*)))
            |--Sort(ORDER BY:([cppev].[Value] ASC, [cppev].[ProductSkeletonID] ASC))
                 |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([cpsr].[ProductID])=([cppev].[ProductID]), RESIDUAL:([dbo].[table1].[ProductID] as [cppev].[ProductID]=[dbo].[table_results].[ProductID] as [cpsr].[ProductID]))
                      |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([dbo].[table_results].[IX_table_results_SearchID] AS [cpsr]), SEEK:([cpsr].[SearchID]=(227568)) ORDERED FORWARD)
                      |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([dbo].[table1].[IX_table1_productskeletonid] AS [cppev]), SEEK:([cppev].[ProductSkeletonID]=(3158) OR [cppev].[ProductSkeletonID]=(3160) OR [cppev].[ProductSkeletonID]=(3191) OR [cppev].[ProductSkeletonID]=(3201)) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

===== Table2 query ======

```
    SELECT cppev.ProductSkeletonID, cppev.Value, COUNT(*) AS Value FROM table2 cppev
    JOIN table_results cpsr ON cppev.ProductID = cpsr.ProductID AND cpsr.SearchID = 227568 
    WHERE cppev.ProductSkeletonID in (3191, 3160, 3158, 3201)
    GROUP BY cppev.ProductSkeletonID, cppev.Value

    Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
    Table 'table2'. Scan count 4, logical reads 584, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
    Table 'table_results'. Scan count 1, logical reads 82, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

    SQL Server Execution Times:
       CPU time = 484 ms,  elapsed time = 796 ms.

  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1005]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1008],0)))
       |--Stream Aggregate(GROUP BY:([cppev].[Value], [cppev].[ProductSkeletonID]) DEFINE:([Expr1008]=Count(*)))
            |--Sort(ORDER BY:([cppev].[Value] ASC, [cppev].[ProductSkeletonID] ASC))
                 |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([cpsr].[ProductID])=([cppev].[ProductID]), RESIDUAL:([auctori_core_v40_D].[dbo].[table2].[ProductID] as [cppev].[ProductID]= [dbo].[table2].[ProductID] as [cpsr].[ProductID]))
                      |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([dbo].[table_results].[IX_table_results_SearchID] AS [cpsr]), SEEK:([cpsr].[SearchID]=(227568)) ORDERED FORWARD)
                      |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([dbo].[table2].[IX_table2_productskeletonid] AS [cppev]), SEEK:([cppev].[ProductSkeletonID]=(3158) OR [cppev].[ProductSkeletonID]=(3160) OR [cppev].[ProductSkeletonID]=(3191) OR [cppev].[ProductSkeletonID]=(3201)) ORDERED FORWARD)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're seeing the cost overhead of using `MAX` types.

While `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is identical to `NVARCHAR(n)` in TSQL and can be stored in-row, it is handled separately by the storage engine because it can be pushed off-row. When off-row it is a `LOB_DATA` allocation unit, rather than `ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA` allocation unit and we can assume from your observations that this carries an overhead.

You can see the two types are internally stored differently with a little [DBCC PAGE spelunking](https://web.archive.org/web/20160124105439/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/06/10/625659.aspx). [Mark Rasmussen](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2028/mark-s-rasmussen) posted example page dumps that show the differences in [What is the Size of the LOB Pointer for (MAX) Types Like Varchar, Varbinary, Etc?](https://improve.dk/what-is-the-size-of-the-lob-pointer-for-max-types-like-varchar-varbinary-etc/)

We can probably assume it's the `GROUP BY` on the `MAX` column that causes the performance difference in your case. I've not tested other operations on a `MAX` type but it might be interesting to do so and see if similar results are seen.

Comment: So you are saying there is extra processing reading a [BLOB Inline Data] vs a plain 'ol varchar? I was expecting significant overhead if it went off row, but all of this data is inline (used dbcc ind).  And why do you think the group by brings this out?

Comment: A little overhead for reading it, lots for any computation on it e.g. `GROUP BY`. @RemusRusanu could likely offer some insight (he'll hopefully see the ping).

Comment: I found another [article](https://sites.google.com/site/mrmbookmarks/msg/sql-performancecomparisonnvarchar4000vsnvarcharmax) that documents the same behavior, even on equals and like.  I wonder if nvarchar(max) uses a less efficient algorithm.