# SQL string field lengths in a db having about 6 different types of addresses, with about 20 markets and environments

Tags: architecture

(Someone suggested I should ask this here too; previously posted on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231335/sql-string-field-lengths-in-a-db-having-about-6-different-types-of-addresses-wi )

I have been advocating lately that all string fields should be ntext / nvarchar(max) - we're using MS SQL Server. The objections seem to be either "it's not a good idea" (without any reason) or "that would allow the customer to send a lot of crap". Since I believe in filtering out the crap before it hits the database, is there a *good* reason why my idea is bad?

My main argument for not limiting the string fields is that I have discovered that we have about six different types of addresses (customer, reseller and so on), with about 20 markets (each having its own database) and environments. I have spotted at least ten different lengths for say Address1 and the same thing happens for other fields. Instead of "standardizing" them and then discovering that we missed something, I suggested that we go ahead and limit the inputs and let the database handle anything.

Does anyone have a pro/con I don't see?

Comment: While I find the relevant question, it's a bad idea as the optimizer chooses really bad plans because it has to assume the worst when you might never go beyond 30 characters for a field

Comment: Martin Smith's answer is a good one on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009694/is-there-an-advantage-to-varchar500-over-varchar8000/

Comment: Hmm, I think this http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47941/35182 is even more compelling.

Comment: I agree, @MaxVernon